# Posting jQuery data with special characthers

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post

I have a quite odd problem. The problem is like this... When I try to pass a string to my controller action (.NET MVC), this one:

```
Small Bubble Roll 3/16" x 1400' x 12" Perforated 3/16 Bubbles 1400 Sq Ft Wrap
```

I checked in the console and I'm getting an server internal error 500... To make things worse I've tested whether the post will work with different kinds of titles like: "super duper amoled TV" or something like , and it works.. I suspect that the issue is because the string contains special characthers like ' and " ...

This is the post method itself:

```
var postData = {
    comment: $('#TextArea1').val(),
    rating: $('input[name=rating]:checked').val(),
    keyword: '@Session["Title"]'
};
```

First post data and now the post itself:

```
$.post("/Analyze/SaveWatchList", postData)
    .done(function (response) {
        // do something with the response here...
    });
});
```

And now the Controller action itself:

```
[ActionName("SaveWatchList")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveWatchList(string comment, string rating, string keyword)
{

}
```

With the title itself that I've shown above, action doesn't gets triggered at all.. Instead  I simply get internal server error 500 in console...

How could I fix this ?

Comment: You can try [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) i.e. `comment: encodeURIComponent($('#TextArea1').val()),`

Comment: There's no special characters in the first posted string which would trip up your ASP code. Have you tried stepping in to the Action to see exactly what the exception is?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The action doesn't gets triggered at all when I pass this value as a string in keyword parameter... It's really odd

Comment: @Satpal on the entire post data object or just keyword parameter??

Comment: If you check the request in the network tab of the console you'll see the HTML of the error page which should give you an exception trace which you can use to diagnose the exact issue

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know that's what I thought the same at first... But when I pass something in parameter like: "super amoled TV" , then action gets triggered, I don't modify the code at all...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan _the post will work with different kinds of titles like: "super duper amoled TV" or something like , and it works_

Comment: [ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult PostProduct(Product obj)
{

Comment: @Lakshay looks good, I was missing this data annotation =D ... Just now gotta replace the invalid quote; and #39; signs with " and ' XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could serialize the `postData` and expect a request object at the action which can further be de-serialized to obtain individual properties.

Model:

```
public class ExampleRequest {
  public string comment {get; set;};
  public string rating {get; set;};
  public string keyword {get; set;};
}
```

Controller Action:

```
[ActionName("SaveWatchList")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveWatchList(ExampleRequest req)
{ 
  var comment = req.comment;
  var rating = req.rating;
  var keyword = req.keyword;
}
```

**Update:**

Json object:

```
var postData = {
      comment: $('#TextArea1').val(),
      rating: $('input[name=rating]:checked').val(),
      keyword: '@Session["Title"]'
};
```

Comment: All parameters are null in this case inside the object when I do it like this =(

Comment: any ideas why this happens ?

Comment: which property is the string with special characters?

Comment: comment and keyword

Comment: Sajal, just tested it with or without special characthers, all of the properties inside the object are null =(

Comment: @User987, do not `JSON.stringify` the `postData` as it would automatically be a json object. See the update to my answer.

Comment: Sajal, it works now but with extra adding the encoding of specific parameter that had special characthers like: encodeURIComponent('@Session["Title"]') ... Without this I keep getting internal error again... And on server side I use: Server.Decode(model.Title);

Comment: Little update.. Gotta add [AllowHtml] data attribute to this property, so then no need for encodeURIComponent method and then to decode it on server side

Comment: I ran the above code and I was able to obtain the comment  - "Small Bubble Roll 3/16" x 1400' x 12" Perforated 3/16 Bubbles 1400 Sq Ft Wrap" at the action without encoding it, since json takes care of that.

Comment: At me it didn't work without adding [AllowHtml] data attribute for some reason =/

Comment: It' looks good mostly though, I end up with a string like this: Small Bubble Roll 3/16&quot; x 1400&#39; x 12&quot; Perforated 3/16 Bubbles 1400 Sq Ft Wrap ... How could I get rid of these  "&quot;" signs at least?

Comment: Aren't you passing string to controller, why do you have to use [AllowHtml]?

Comment: Sajal yes I'm passing the string (entire object) to the controller... But if I don't use [AllowHtml] data annotation in the class that you've created for keyword property I get internal server error when trying to post data from form

Comment: What does your @Session["Title"] contain? Rather than sending the entire object, type cast it to string and pass on that value to controller using keyword property

Comment: Sajal, the Session["Title"] contains the title: Small Bubble Roll 3/16" x 1400' x 12" Perforated 3/16 Bubbles 1400 Sq Ft Wrap

Comment: Like Session["Title"].ToString()?

Comment: Yes, certainly.

Comment: Is there a neat data annotation which would help me to remove the &qoute; and &#39; signs ? Actually not remove, just replace &qutote; with "" and &#39 with single qoute ( ' )